# How to store content of csv file in an Array in JavaScript using VS Code

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I am using **VS Code** and running Javascript. Beside VS Code I have installed **Node** in my computer. I am using windows. I have `csv` file in the same folder as my `.js` file.

**How do I save the content of the `csv` file into an array?**

Let's say my `csv` file have this content and I want to store it as an array variable  `A`:

`101,MS,100000
102,LS,80000
103,TS,60000
104,VB,200000
105,PB,180000
106,AB,160000`

Comment: I have tried to follow many instructions on the net but I haven't been able to succeed. Maybe because I have a background in Math and not Computer Science. So while I can setup algorithms for numerical purposes, I have difficulty understanding some very basics of Computer Science. The latest article I followed is this: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/nodejs/1204/read-csv-file-using-nodejs

Comment: Use `Split()`. Works like this: `var A = yourCsvFileAsAString.split(",")`. To read your file as a string, get it with a XMLHttpRequest. Links: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have node installed, you could use a npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-string to do so.

They have listed out all the ways that can be used to generate an array.

Comment: Yes to a CSV lib! CSV files are a lot more complex than split/join on commas.

Comment: Yes, exactly! :D